# Sort an array of objects if property exists

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects. Out of each of these objects onle few of them have a property and I want to sort the array putting those objects at top which have that property.

Ex -

```
arr= [{key1: "obj1val1", key2 :"obj1val2"}, 
      {key2 :"obj2val2"}, 
      {key1: "obj3val3", key2 :"obj3val3"},
      {key2 :"obj4val1"},
      {key1: "obj5val1", key2 :"obj5val2"}
]
```

Sorted by key1

```
Expected Result - [{key1: "obj1val1", key2 :"obj1val2"}, 
                   {key1: "obj3val3", key2 :"obj3val3"},
                   {key1: "obj5val1", key2 :"obj5val2"}, 
                   {key2 :"obj2val2"}, 
                   {key2 :"obj4val1"}]
```

I have tried below approach-

```
sort : function(arr) {
              var copyArr = arr.slice();
              var newArr = [];
              for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
                if(arr[i].key1){
                  newArr.push(arr[i]);
                    copyArr.splice(i, 1);
                }
              }
              Array.prototype.push.apply(newArr, copyArr);
              return newArr;
            }
```

Not exactly but I see discrepancy from the above approach. For a array bigger length, some of the objects which have key1 are not moved to top.
Can this be done by internal `sort` method of javascript? If yes, how will the custom function compare ?

Can only support ES5 methods.

Comment: Don't use `splice` while you are iterating.

Comment: Do you actually want to sort them by comparing all of them with each other, or do you want to keep the order but move those with the property to the top? In the latter case, don't use `sort`.

Comment: @Bergi That is why I have copied the original array and spliced the copied array. I want  to keep the order but move the property to top

Comment: Still, the indices of the other elements change when you `splice` out one element.

Comment: Just use `var withProp = [], withoutProp = []; … if ("key1" in arr[i]) withProp.push(arr[i]); else withoutProp.push(arr[i]); …`. Don't copy anything beforehand or try to splice from it during a loop.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Can this be done by internal sort method of javascript

Yes: Simply prefer the entry that has the property:

```
arr.sort(function(left, right) {
    return left.hasOwnProperty("key1") ? -1 : right.hasOwnProperty("key1") ? 1 : 0
});
```

Live Example:

```js
var arr = [
    {key1: "obj1val1", key2 :"obj1val2"}, 
    {key2 :"obj2val2"}, 
    {key1: "obj3val3", key2 :"obj3val3"},
    {key2 :"obj4val1"},
    {key1: "obj5val1", key2 :"obj5val2"}
];
arr.sort(function(left, right) {
    return left.hasOwnProperty("key1") ? -1 : right.hasOwnProperty("key1") ? 1 : 0
});
console.log(arr);
```

If you also want to sort by that property's value:

```
arr.sort(function(left, right) {
    var leftHas = left.hasOwnProperty("key1");
    var rightHas = right.hasOwnProperty("key1");
    if (leftHas && rightHas) {
      return left.key1.localeCompare(right.key1);
    }
    return leftHas ? -1 : rightHas ? 1 : 0;
});
```

Live Example:

```js
var arr = [
    {key1: "obj1val1", key2 :"obj1val2"}, 
    {key2 :"obj2val2"}, 
    {key1: "obj3val3", key2 :"obj3val3"},
    {key2 :"obj4val1"},
    {key1: "obj5val1", key2 :"obj5val2"}
];
arr.sort(function(left, right) {
    var leftHas = left.hasOwnProperty("key1");
    var rightHas = right.hasOwnProperty("key1");
    if (leftHas && rightHas) {
      return left.key1.localeCompare(right.key1);
    }
    return leftHas ? -1 : rightHas ? 1 : 0;
});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Hi TJ..can you share an ES5 version of this answer?

Comment: @RahulB - Wow, second nature to use arrow functions. :-) Done.

Comment: Gosh, I did wrote this logic but messed up the return statements in the ternary. Neat solution. Should have reached SO a little earlier, wasted half of my sleeping time. Thanks TJ

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working snippet that gives your requested result and is easily extended.  It uses the native array `sort`.

```js
arr = [{
    key1: "obj1val1",
    key2: "obj1val2"
  },
  {
    key2: "obj2val2"
  },
  {
    key1: "obj3val3",
    key2: "obj3val3"
  },
  {
    key2: "obj4val1"
  },
  {
    key1: "obj5val1",
    key2: "obj5val2"
  }
]

const sorted = arr.sort((a, b) => {
  const k1 = a.key1 === undefined ? 0 : 1
  const k2 = b.key1 === undefined ? 0 : 2
  return k2- k1
})
console.log(sorted)
```

Answer (score 0):

A kind of janky way you can do it is:

```
arr.filter(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty('key1')).concat(arr.filter(obj => !obj.hasOwnProperty('key1')));
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/arraybrain/arraybrain

for complex array stuff, you can use it